# Hardware Multithreading and Simultaneous Multithreading(SMT)

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'm reading [Multithreading (computer architecture) - Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)), aka hardware threading, and I'm trying to understand the second paragraph:

> (p2): Where multiprocessing systems include multiple complete processing units in one or more cores, multithreading aims to increase utilization of **a single core** by using **thread-level parallelism**, as well as instruction-level parallelism.

while the link to **thread-level parallelism** says:

> ([Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_parallelism#Description)): **Thread-level parallelism (TLP)** is the parallelism inherent in an application that runs multiple threads at once. This type of parallelism is found largely in applications written for commercial servers such as ...

which is not so useful... So I read **task parallelism** above, since I guess TLP is a subtype of it:

> **Task parallelism** (also known as function parallelism and control parallelism) is a form of parallelization of computer code **across multiple processors** in parallel computing environments. Task parallelism focuses on distributing tasks—concurrently performed by processes or threads—**across different processors**.

Question: If thread-level parallelism is task parallelism, and task parallelism is for parallelization across multiple processors, how *increase utilization **of a single core** by using thread-level parallelism* work?

Guessing: I guess for TLP, it should mean across multiple **logical** processors, i.e. hardware threads in the perspective of OS, correct?

---

Another minor issue is that for my first link, Multithreading:

> **In computer architecture, multithreading** is the ability of a central processing unit (CPU) (or a single core in a multi-core processor) to execute multiple processes or threads **concurrently**, supported by the operating system.

And in (p2) it *aim to increase utilization of a single core by using thread-level **parallelism***? What a contradiction.

Comment: The Wikipedia articles about software engineering are not very good, you are much better off with an introductory book about operating system design.  Increasing the utilization of a single core with threading is not so obvious, but could happen when the code it currently executes cannot continue.  Waiting for I/O is a standard reason, like reading from a file.  Instead of the core doing nothing while the disk drive grinds away, it can switch to another thread that is waiting for execution.  Any modern OS does that.

Comment: @HansPassant: Oh... it's sad, I also asked about a similar issue at computer science before I post this here and another expert says my first link *is an okey place to start*...

Comment: @HansPassant: May I ask you that is it possible to run threads within the same core in parallel?

Comment: @ptr_user7813604: it wouldn't be "running" if speaking technically. an OS (with preemptive multithreading) has a scheduler which "runs" each thread for a tiny amount of time and then "preempts" it and "runs" another thread. if the thread is waiting for something (e.g. for mutex or just sleeps) OS (usually) immediately interrupts it and switches to another thread. So you can have two threads on a single core that kind of "runs" in parallel but actually at any given moment only one of them actually executes something and still they can provide better core utilization than one thread

Comment: @AndriyTylychko: Thanks! (and what's the technical term...?)

Comment: @ptr_user7813604: I'd say it's "preemptive execution"

Comment: It is possible, hyper-threading is mentioned in the article.  Badly out of context, it could only confuse the reader even more.  Do visit the library.

Comment: Cross-site near duplicate: [How does a single thread run on multiple cores?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/350024)  (it doesn't, but SMT will let multiple software threads keep the execution units of one physical core fed with work to do.  i.e. higher utlization of the core's execution units.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we should base off wiki definitions, the wording there is not accurate enough to merit searching for contradictions.

First, I would describe task parallelism as a form of parallelism inherent to some algorithm or problem, where there could be a functional decomposition into multiple tasks with different nature, that can run concurrently. Alternative forms of parallelism include for example spatial or data decomposition, where the problem can be broken into different parts of the data or the input layout (e.g., array ranges, matrix tiles, image parts...).

Thread-level parallelism is a different taxonomy, it is any form of parallelism that can be extracted for utilization by a multi-threaded system. It requires the decomposition to be coarse grained enough to allow the different threads to run independently (otherwise the synchronization overhead required would make it useless).
The alternative for that is for example ILP (instruction level parallelism) which is when a single thread context can extract parallelism within the code by running over a deep out-of-order machine that can schedule based on readiness. This allows more fine-grained parallelism and less programmer involvement usually, but limits the parallelism to the depth of the OOO window.

On a related topic - be careful not to confuse simultaneous execution and concurrent one.

Thread level parallelism can be used by extracting task-level parallelism or other forms of algorithm decomposition from the code. It can then be run on a system that is single-core (preemptive), or multi-threaded. The latter type can be achieved through multi-core systems, simultaneous multi-threading or both (common processors usually have many cores, and may of them support SMT on top of that).

Comment: My upvote is based on if task parallelism is actually run concurrently but "seems to" parallel on task-level granularity. Sorry I didn't understand it yesterday.

Comment: I don't quite understand this line: *Thread level parallelism can be used by extracting task-level parallelism or other forms of algorithm decomposition from the code.*

Comment: Thread level is just a way to describe parallelism through multiple threads (as opposed to ILP for example), it doesn't describe what you run there. The different ways of breaking down (or decomposing) an algorithm into multiple parts that can run independently is a different taxonomy, and task parallelism is one of these ways

Comment: Then TLP should include task parallelism?

Answer (score 0):

I think my intuition should be correct, it is either:

1. > Task parallelism (also known as function parallelism and control parallelism) is a form of parallelization of computer code across multiple processors in parallel computing environments.

   should be updated to:

   > Task parallelism (also known as function parallelism and control parallelism) is a form of parallelization of computer code across multiple **logical** processors in parallel computing environments.

   to include the possibility of hyper threading.
2. No update, but task parallelism is focus on cross-processor parallelism while for TLP it should mean

   > Thread-level parallelism is a form of parallelization of computer code across multiple **logical** processors in parallel computing environments.

   again, to include the possibility of hyper threading.

---

Useful resource:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnS50lJicXc
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading

  especially [this line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading#Details):

  > The name multithreading is ambiguous, because not only can **multiple threads** be executed **simultaneously** on one CPU core, but **also multiple tasks** (with different page tables, different task state segments, different protection rings, different I/O permissions, etc.).

  So for the minor issue, see [Concurrent computing - #Introduction - p1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing#Introduction):

  > The concept of concurrent computing is frequently confused with the related but distinct concept of parallel computing,[2][3] although both can be described as "multiple processes executing during the same period of time". In parallel computing, execution occurs at the same physical instant: for example, on separate processors of a multi-processor machine, with the goal of speeding up computations—parallel computing is impossible on a (one-core) single processor, as only one computation can occur at any instant (during any single clock cycle).